# How to Convert Time to Json Format with user given time?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm giving a time period and converting to J SON, but J SON object returns time 15 lesser than the user time period. How to get the same time period in J SON object.

Example:

```
var starttime = 2015-05-26T00:00:00;var jsonconvert= new Date(starttime).toJSON();
```

i get an ouput of "2015-05-25T 18:30:00.000Z"

How to get an output of time which i have given ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[toJSON()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) method returns UTC date but Date() expects "Local Date" . So there are two ways either you give date in UTC to Date() constructor or add your Timezone to the Date Object later

> **First Way** (Setting a UTC date instead of Local date using [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC))

```
var starttime = "2015-05-26T00:00:00";
var date=new Date(starttime);    //create a local date
var date= new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate(),date.getHours(),date.getMinutes(),date.getSeconds()));
//this is UTC date set using Date.UTC
jsonconvert=date.toJSON(); //returns the UTC Date
alert(jsonconvert)
```

> **Second Way** (Adding TimeZone to Date so during toJSON it will subtract the timeZone and return the correct date)

```
var starttime = "2015-05-26T00:00:00";
var date=new Date(starttime);
date.setTime( date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000 );//Add TimeZone to Local Date 
jsonconvert=date.toJSON()
alert(jsonconvert)
```

**PS** :

1. [date.getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) is subtracted as it return negative
   value if time is ahead of UTC and vice versa
2. You also have to append Z to your string to make it to correct
   UTC datetime string

Comment: Thanks Ankit, But the problem is solved in IE but not in Google chrome.. before adding this step in google chrome it gives the user given time, but in IE it gives me the UTC time. after adding its started vice versa

Comment: @AravindE You need to append Z after your date to get correct datetime string

Comment: @ Ankit Thanks, I have done that, I have two dates one is start date and start time another one is end date and end time, as per your instruction my start date and time comes as user input type. but my end date and time seems to behind, (it goes -15hrs back of user input time).Could you please  update and give me the example through fiddle.

Comment: What are you inputting as end date